# Facebook div empty

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

html:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init();

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            runFbInitCriticalCode(); 
            console.log(response);
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
});
```

After the code executes, the div is filled with iframes and other facebook tags, but it's empty. I don't see anything in the page, so what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Replace `facebook-jssdk` with `fb-root` in js file second last line in given code.

```
(document, 'script', 'fb-root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    if(typeof(FB) != 'undefined') {
        FB.init({
            appId: facebookAppId, xfbml: true, status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true
        });
    }
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>
```

In my case `facebookAppId` is a JavaScript variable with your Facebook application id. You need to create one [here](https://developers.facebook.com/). Only after this you can take advantage on their JS API.

More info [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/).

Comment: I can't find where to register my application and get the APPID, can you give me a specific URL ?, also in the documentation is said that APPID is optional, is really optional?

Comment: Should be here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps. Then click "+ Create New App"

Comment: And yeah - it's optional to call `init` method, but is required to call `getLoginStatus`.

Comment: i need to show only the social group in the site, is it required the app id for this?

Comment: You will have to use graph API calls or FQL queries, so yes - you will have to create fb application as well.